# Magento keep the base css or get rid of it?

Tags: magento

Ok so I looked everywhere and took a few tutorials. For the first two themes I built in magento.. I got rid of the base styles.css file.. but then in trying to theme the entire magento pages.. I skipped over a few minor pages and they were all jacked up since the original css wasn\’t there. I don\’t want that mistake to keep happening..

Are you suppose to know ALL pages that should be styled in your local.css file? Or should you keep the base styles.css file and override it or copy it into your local.css and change it up that way? It just has a lot of unecessary code and it\’s a little too large to keep editing..

I\’ve been thinking for the past 2 hours and can\’t seem to find a good solution. So everything inside the template/page directory (not everything, but a few files like the 1-column, 2-column, 3-column, header, footer, etc) should be edited into your new theme right? Like copied, pasted, and then edited?

I\’m doing the local.xml file the right way and not touching any of the other .xml files to edit the blocks. I\’m just stumped on how to do the whole css stuff.. since I\’m unsure how many pages and what pages magento comes with if I get rid of the css to make sure to check and style in my local.css..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It depends". Official Magento recommendation for this (such as they exist, it's what I teach in the dev class) is to leave whatever default theme stylesheet in effect & overrule/add to its directives in your own stylesheet. I also point our that it's reasonable to take the core stylesheet and modify it in your custom theme, as the entire point behind the theme hierarchy is maintaining as clear an upgrade path as possible. Be prepared to do a three way diff when upgrading Magento if you've used the latter approach.

Comment: So would it be more be more effective to copy and paste their css into your local css or keep their css included in the head and add your own css with the !important attributes when overriding? The second (overrides) seems.. like a pain in the a** since !important can get VERY ugly..

Comment: In your case I would copy *`styles.css`* into your custom theme and implement customizations therein.